# Woocommerce Product category id from product id

Tags: woocommerce, categories, product

I'm trying to get the main category id in the product page using the product id with no success.

help please :-|

I have to know if product is from a category X and change manually the price

Comment: What do you mean by "change manually the price" you want to set discount for that category ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example get woo-commerce category id from product id

**get category for product page**

```
global $post;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_id = $term->term_id;
    break;
}
```

Comment: @GilJosef if the answer help you try to accept it and give up vote..Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking:

```php
/**
 * Get products categories given a product ID.
 *
 * @author Nabil Kadimi
 * @link   https://stackoverflow.com/a/46714456/358906
 *
 * @param  Integer $product_id The product ID.
 * @param  String  $fields     Which fields to retrieve all, ids, names,
 *                             count, id=>parent, id=>slug or id=>name.
 *                             See WP_Term_Query constructor for more info.
 * @return Array               The categories.
 */
function so34274948_wc_get_categories_by_product_id( $product_id, $fields ) {
    return wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat', [ 'fields' => $fields ] );
}
```

Example:

```php
$categories = so34274948_wc_get_categories_by_product_id( 123, 'ids' );
```